# Undefined reference to siglongjump

Tags: c, posix

I am solving Linux/POSIX questions and I can't figure out what is wrong with my headers/library etc.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <setjmp.h>
jmp_buf buf;

void handler(int sig){ siglongjump(buf, 1); }
int main(){
    signal(SIGUSR1, handler);
    if(sigsetjmp(buf,1)==0)
        printf("A");
    if(fork() == 0){ // child process
        kill(getpid(), SIGUSR1); exit(0);}
```

I included: `<stdio.h>`, `<signal.h>`, `<stdlib.h>` and `<setjmp.h>`; I'm also compiling with `-lc` option.

But I'm getting an undefined reference to `siglongjump`.  Why?

Comment: When posting a question regarding errors, please always provide the errors, unedited and complete. Also, *describe* what happens, what you expect to happen, etc. Just saying "this doesn't work, what's wrong" does not give us enough to go on to even guess.

Answer (score 3):

The function name is misspelled. It's not `siglongjump` but [`siglongjmp`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/longjmp.3.html) :)